# WPF bind to Grid Cell Width/Height From Style (Application.xaml)

Tags: wpf, styles

So I basically want to have a textblock that gets it's width and height from the grid "cell" that it is placed in by style. I figured out how to do this with the grid width and height but can't get this to work on the cell (column and row definition). This is fairly simple if binding on an element name and naming the definitions. I think this would be fairly simple using a stackpanel as the textblocks parent, but I'd rather avoid using a stackpanel in this case.

Here is what I have:

```
<Style x:Key="HeaderTextblock" TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Grid}}}"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type RowDefinition}}}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Background">
            <Setter.Value>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF3CD1E0" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFE0F2F3" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

This of course sets the width to the grid's width, what I want is to set the width and height to the column and row definition. As you can see I have tried to use the same type of code for the row definition, but this does not work.

Thank you

Comment: Why don't you just set `HorizontalAlignment`, and `VerticalAlignment` to `Stretch`?

Comment: Simply.... That would be to easy. Duh!!. Thanks Mr. Eason.